# Python: Combine elements from 4 lists and skip combination of lists with which have duplicates in it

Tags: python

I'm a bit loss...
I have the following dataset as input (normally one category more to simplify now three):

```
category = 
{"A" :[1002, 1004,1003,1008], 
"B": [1002, 1004,1009], 
"C":[1002,1003,1006,1005]}
```

As output I want all possible combinations of the elements under the restriction that only combining is done if the element is not in the other categories. For example 1002 is in all categories so there is no combination possible. 1004 is in A and B so it can just be combined with an element from C which has no duplicate in A and B or nothing and so on.

Output for this Example should be:

```
Out: [[1002],[1003],[1008],[1009],[1004], [1006],[1006,1008,1009],[1005,1008,1009],[1003,1009][1005,1008],[1004,1005],[1008,1006],[1009,1008],[1005,1009]]
```

*I hope I didn't forget any combination please let me know and I update

maybe someone can help me,

I have now tried a few hours around to first combine all Elements, sort the Output and remove the duplicates in the lists and sublists. But now I don't how I can filter out my still "wrong combinations" even further. So I guess that's the wrong way...

that's my Start....

```
def get_list_of_lists(list_of_tuples):
    list_of_lists = []                                                          
    for tuple in list_of_tuples:
        list_of_lists.append(list(tuple))

    return list_of_lists

def rem_dup(lis):
    y, s = [], set()
    for t in lis:
        w = tuple(sorted(t)) if isinstance(t, list) else t
        if not w in s:
            y.append(t)
            s.add(w)
    return y


category = {"A" :[3001,1002,1001,8002,2002], "B": [4002,7001,3001,1002,2002], "C":[4002,4001,1002,5001], "D":[4001,1002,1001,2002]}
s = [category["A"], category["B"], category["C"], category["D"]]
s1=list(itertools.product(*s))
s2 = get_list_of_lists(s1)
for sublists in s2:
    sublists.sort()
inp = s2
out = [rem_dup(i) if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in rem_dup(inp)] 
new_out = []
for part in out:
    if part not in new_out:
        new_out.append(part)
out = new_out
```

Comment: At least to me, this problem is a little difficult to follow. Would it be possible to reduce your example `category` dictionary to 3 elements of length 3 so that you can include the entire expected output as an [mre]? Or would that oversimplify the problem too much?

Comment: Thanks for that advice. I dont know wether reducing will catch all the exceptions. But as I think my first code will lead to an wrong expection what I am aiming at. So I might to think about how to adjust it a little.

Comment: Can one list contain duplicate elements? E.g. would "A": [1002, 1002, 1004,  1003, 1008] be valid ?

Comment: That will normaly not occur. So no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the identities of the categories and the order (of the resulting combinations or of the numbers in each combination) can be ignored.

```py
lst = [{1002, 1004, 1003, 1008},
       {1002, 1004, 1009},
       {1002, 1003, 1006, 1005}]

mask = dict()
for s in lst:
    for num in s:
        mask[num] = mask.get(num, set()) | s

def get_combs(lst):
    if lst == []:
        return [[]]
    output = []
    output += get_combs(lst[1:]) # not picking any number at this category
    for num in lst[0]:
        sublst_masked = [s - mask[num] for s in lst[1:]]
        output += [[num] + comb for comb in get_combs(sublst_masked)]
    return output

output = get_combs(lst)
# print(output) # this might have duplicates
output = set(tuple(sorted(l)) for l in output)
print(output) # {(1002,), (1008,), (1005,), (1006, 1009), (1006, 1008, 1009), (1004, 1006), (1004,), (1006, 1008), (1008, 1009), (1005, 1008, 1009), (1005, 1009), (1009,), (1003, 1009), (1004, 1005), (1006,), (1005, 1008), (1003,), ()}
```

Note that I changed the data structure of the input; now it is a list of sets, without category names.

The idea is to define a "mask" for each number appearing in the input; for example, `mask[1003]` outputs `{1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1008}`, which means in a list of numbers that contains `1003`, these numbers cannot appear. So for example, if you picked `1003` at the first category, then you will only pick number `1009` (which is not in the mask) from the second category (or none). Once you picked `1003` and `1009`, then in the third category every number is in the masks corresponding to `1003` or `1009`, so you cannot pick any number from the third category. So `[1003, 1009]` is one of the combinations in the solution, while its super-lists further containing a number in the third category are not.

You might probably need a (nested) for loop for each category to pick a number from the category, but I implemented it using a recursive function `get_combs()` to for this looping, picking, and masking procedure. I chose to use a recursive function, because I don't know a simple way to generalize the depth of the nested loops to an arbitrary number of categories.

Please verify the output I provided at the last line of the code. (I've checked that your example output is a subset of this output.) The result contains an empty tuple, which correspondes to picking no number at each category. But surely you can just remove it if necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats a way i would've never thought of alone. It works well! Yes the Identities are not relevant as you stated out, just for the person who creates the input. The empty tuple is fine.  
I checked your output and you are right. I forgot some entries in my output and will edit it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.product` to get cartesian porduct of all options, and then reduce it to non-duplicated ones:

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> list(map(set,itertools.product(*category.values())))

[{1002}, {1002, 1003}, {1002, 1006}, ..., {1008, 1009, 1005}]
```

To further remove elements, that repeat because of 2 or more same elements in groups, like e.g.
`{1002, 1004, 1003}` and `{1004, 1002, 1003}`:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.unique(list(map(lambda y: list(set(sorted(y))),itertools.product(*category.values()))))
array([list([1002]), list([1002, 1003]), ...,
       list([1009, 1004, 1006])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that shortens my already written code immensly. And builds up more Numpy and Itertools usage understanding. But taht wont help the main problem unfortunately...  It still does not remove the entries like [[1002],[1003],[1005]] but I know, that was not part of your answer. So thanks :)